# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined" BUT still displayed on alert and console.log

Tags: javascript, ajax

I get a **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valeurs' of undefined** but the `alert()` and `console.log()` are displaying the datas.

Here is the code:

```
var item = document.getElementById('inputData').value;

$.ajax({
    url : 'php/modele.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data :{
        textValue : item
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(code_html, statut){

        var newhtml = '';

        console.log(code_html);
        
        for(var i = 0; i <= code_html.length; i++){

            alert(code_html[i]['valeurs']); // working but the error is pointing here. Line 21.

            newhtml += i+") "+code_html[i]['valeurs']+"<br>"; // not working
            console.log(code_html[i]['valeurs']); // working

        }

        alert(newhtml); //not displayed
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = newhtml;
        
    },
    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
        alert('error: '+erreur+' resultat: '+resultat);
    },
    complete : function(resultat, statut){ 

    }
 });
```

As you can see here, `alert()` and `console.log()` are displaying what I want.
[Alert is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Upwg.png)
[console.log is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqEmY.png)

But the `innerhtml` never comes because of the error. So I dont get the data in my html page.

Also if I change this line `newhtml += i+") "+code_html[i]['valeurs']+"<br>"; // not working` by doing `newhtml += i+") "+code_html[0]['valeurs']+"<br>"; // not working` it works and display the value "bonjour" 4 times.

Comment: Your `for` loop test should use `<` not `<=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays starts from 0, so if an array has length 4, the last element has index 3... therefore instead of

```
for(var i = 0; i <= code_html.length; i++)
```

you should use

```
for(var i = 0; i < code_html.length; i++)
                ^^^
```

the values were displayed because the first 4 iterations are fine, it's just the last one that causes the problem

Comment: After some hours of overthinking that was as simple as that. Thanks you !